# How to detect when custom keyboard is in floating mode?

Tags: ios, swift, custom-keyboard

I'm making a custom keyboard that I'll mainly be using outside of the host app. I would need to know when the keyboard appears in floating keyboard mode. For this, according to the documentation, I set a NotificationCenter observer in the KeyboardViewController, but it is not called. where am i stuck?

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidShow(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func keyboardDidShow(_ notification: Notification) {
        guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else { return }
        guard let screen = notification.object as? UIScreen,
              // Get the keyboard’s frame at the end of its animation.
              let keyboardFrameEnd = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect else { return }
        
        // Use that screen to get the coordinate space to convert from.
        let fromCoordinateSpace = screen.coordinateSpace
        
        // Get your view's coordinate space.
        let toCoordinateSpace: UICoordinateSpace = view
        
        // Convert the keyboard's frame from the screen's coordinate space to your view's coordinate space.
        let convertedKeyboardFrameEnd = fromCoordinateSpace.convert(keyboardFrameEnd, to: toCoordinateSpace)
    }
```

The keyboardDidShow function is never called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found only one solution: The value of `view.frame.width` is already available in the `viewDidAppear` event. In all previously activated events, this is still 0. So here, if this does not match the width of the `UIScreen`, the keyboard is displayed in floating mode.